# Genetic differences between Africans and non-Africans due to cross-breeding with Neanderthals?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, hybridization

It is estimated that soon after the "out of Africa event" there was some interbreeding between *Homo sapiens sapiens* and *Homo neanderthalensis*. All non-African peoples are thought to have around $2\%$ of their DNA from Neanderthals due to this cross-breeding event.

Can it be estimated how much of the genetic difference/distance between Africans and non-Africans is due to this mixing event?

Comment: @bob1 If you take two populations identical in allele frequency and crossbreed one of those with Neanderthals you would initially expect close to 100% of the difference to be due to the crossbreeding event.

Comment: Yes, indeed. However, how many generations since the cross-over event between us and Neanderthal, and what is the genetic difference now?

Comment: Multiple cross-over events are thought to have occurred, (possibly more in some populations than others, not sure).

Comment: @JiminyCricket for Neanderthals? I think only a single admixture (not cross-over, that’s recombination) event occurred. You may be thinking of multiple admixture events with Denisovans.

Comment: 1 to 2 percent according to a different source :  https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/31/science/neanderthal-dna-africa.html#:~:text=From%20DNA%20recovered%20from%20the,percent%20to%202%20percent%20Neanderthal.

Comment: Admixture, the genetic merging of parental populations resulting in mixed ancestry  :  https://academic.oup.com/gbe/article/15/5/evad066/7145698

Comment: 1-4% of the genome of present-day people outside Africa are inherited from Neanderthal ancestors. ( another source:  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36167050/

Comment: Why don't you compose an answer @envs_h_gang_5, you seem to have the basis of one there.